# WebStorm creates method in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, jsdoc

When the instance of `foo` is initialized inline, it infers even without JSDoc that the method to add belongs to `Foo`.

[image]

By clicking enter, this results in the expected result:

```js
class Foo {

    addThisMethod() {
        
    }
}

class Bar {
    foo = new Foo();
    start(){
        this.foo.addThisMethod();
    }
}
```

However, in real life, `foo` is initialized through the constructor. I even wrote the JSDoc twice to tell the IDE foo is `Foo`.

[image]

But when I add a new method, it gives me 3 wrong options.

What can I do to make the IDE know that the method should be created in `Foo` class ?